# How to access values in QVector from other cpp files

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Good afternoon,

Here's what I intend to do: I have a class SERIAL which contains 8 QVectors that hold values I'm receiving over serial port.

```cpp
class SERIAL : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

public:
    SERIAL();
    ~SERIAL();
    QVector<double> ch0_array, mean_ch0_array,
                    ch1_array, mean_ch1_array,
                    ch2_array, mean_ch2_array,
                    ch3_array, mean_ch3_array,
                    ch4_array, mean_ch4_array,
                    ch5_array, mean_ch5_array,
                    ch6_array, mean_ch6_array,
                    ch7_array, mean_ch7_array;
}
```

I want to plot each set of data in real time in 8 other classes each with its own QDialog, called plot0 to plot8. But I'm not able to understand how to share the data from this class to other classes. 
I've tried including `serial.h` file to plot cpp files and I'm not able to access the vectors from there because of the error `invalid use of non static data member`.

Does anyone have an idea about this as I'm pretty bad in C++.

Comment: Please show how do you refer to the vector from plot cpp.

Comment: Do you access the `QVector` members over a valid instance of the `SERIAL` class ?

Comment: You can't access the vector in another class via `SERIAL::ch0_array` you need an instance of the SERIAL class.

Comment: For a class A to access the members of an instance of class B then A should hold a reference member variable to the B instance and this reference gets passed via A's constructor.

Comment: have mercy for future maintainer (probably yourself) and use `QVector<ChanelData>` where `struct ChanelData { QVector<double> ch, mean; };` or other similar approach. Any variable which has index in its name is very bad practice.